# How do I arrange elements in an array within array of struct in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I arrange elements in an array within array of struct?

```
with races as(
select "800m" race, "Rudisha" name,23.4 s1, 26.3 s2, 26.4 s3, 26.1 s4 union all
select "800m" race, "Makhloufi" name,24.5 , 25.4, 26.6, 26.1 union all
select "800m" race, "Murphy" name,23.9, 26.0, 27.0, 26.0 union all
select "800m" race, "Bosse" name,23.6, 26.2, 26.5, 27.1 union all
select "800m" race, "Rotich" name,24.7, 25.6, 26.9, 26.4 union all
select "800m" race, "Lewandowski" name,25.0, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2 union all 
select "800m" race, "Kipketer" name,23.2, 26.1, 27.3, 29.4 union all
select "800m" race, "Berian" name,23.7, 26.1, 27.0, 29.3
)
```

I tried the following query, but not working.

```
select race,array(select x splits from unnest(arr.splits)x order by x )from
(select race,[struct(name as name, [s1,s2,s3,s4] as splits)]arr from races)
```

Comment: clarify expected result/output

Comment: expected output is  name and their splits in ascending order

Comment: provide example of what exactly you want it to look like for at least one row

Comment: 800m  Murphy 23.9, 26.0, 26.0, 27.0

Comment: whare is here array, struct, etc?!

Comment: so, you just need to arrange values in s1, s2, s3, s4 columns such that they are sorted across same s1, s2, s3, s4 - is this correct?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so, you just need to arrange values in s1, s2, s3, s4 columns such that they are sorted across same s1, s2, s3, s4 ? -  yes you are correct

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  race,
  name,
  splits[OFFSET(0)] AS s1,
  splits[OFFSET(1)] AS s2,
  splits[OFFSET(2)] AS s3,
  splits[OFFSET(3)] AS s4
FROM (
  SELECT 
    race,
    name,
    ARRAY(SELECT s FROM UNNEST([s1, s2, s3, s4]) s ORDER BY s) splits
  FROM `project.dataset.races`
)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.races` AS (
  SELECT "800m" race, "Rudisha" name,23.4 s1, 26.3 s2, 26.4 s3, 26.1 s4 UNION ALL
  SELECT "800m" race, "Makhloufi" name,24.5 , 25.4, 26.6, 26.1 UNION ALL
  SELECT "800m" race, "Murphy" name,23.9, 26.0, 27.0, 26.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT "800m" race, "Bosse" name,23.6, 26.2, 26.5, 27.1 UNION ALL
  SELECT "800m" race, "Rotich" name,24.7, 25.6, 26.9, 26.4 UNION ALL
  SELECT "800m" race, "Lewandowski" name,25.0, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT "800m" race, "Kipketer" name,23.2, 26.1, 27.3, 29.4 UNION ALL
  SELECT "800m" race, "Berian" name,23.7, 26.1, 27.0, 29.3
)
SELECT
  race,
  name,
  splits[OFFSET(0)] AS s1,
  splits[OFFSET(1)] AS s2,
  splits[OFFSET(2)] AS s3,
  splits[OFFSET(3)] AS s4
FROM (
  SELECT 
    race,
    name,
    ARRAY(SELECT s FROM UNNEST([s1, s2, s3, s4]) s ORDER BY s) splits
  FROM `project.dataset.races`
)
```

with result / output as

```sql
Row race    name        s1      s2      s3      s4   
1   800m    Murphy      23.9    26.0    26.0    27.0     
2   800m    Bosse       23.6    26.2    26.5    27.1     
3   800m    Lewandowski 25.0    25.7    26.3    27.2     
4   800m    Makhloufi   24.5    25.4    26.1    26.6     
5   800m    Rudisha     23.4    26.1    26.3    26.4     
6   800m    Kipketer    23.2    26.1    27.3    29.4     
7   800m    Berian      23.7    26.1    27.0    29.3     
8   800m    Rotich      24.7    25.6    26.4    26.9
```